# Domain registrar holding on to domain name

Tags: domains, domain-registrar

We have a customer based in Kenya who owns a co.ke domain name.
The registrar refuses to re-assign the nameservers to ours for some reason unknown, and indirectly insists that our customer hosts her webapplication on their servers.

Is there any action you can take to force them to either

(a) release the domainname

(b) assign the desired nameservers

(c) transfer the domain to another registrar, who is more compliant with our request

I'm greatful for any information you may have regarding this. Especially anything that holds legal meaning in case they really try to fight us in this. I'm not sure how things work in Kenya but it doesn't sound right that a registrar can hold claims on a domainname registered by request of another company.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Kenic](http://www.kenic.or.ke/) is in charge of the .ke top level domain. I would contact them using their [dispute settlement procedure](http://www.kenic.or.ke/index.php/governance/dispute-settlement).

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to point the `nameservers`, if you have access to the domains DNS settings outside of the `nameservers` then you could just point to another `IP` with `A-Records` and pick the domain up a your chosen hosts end - most companies support this feature.

Comment: True, but we wish to handle the dns through our own dns servers to utilize the capabilities of our hosting environment to the full extent.

Comment: @JonasB it's a better approach to be sure, just thought I'd make the point in case you hadn't considered it.